# How to isolate PrimeFaces Widget from being affected by main site CSS

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a (p:dataTable) Primefaces widget not rendering properly within the templates of the containing main site, presumably affected by higher level global CSS settings which are however mandatory.

Is there a way to isolate the widget from wider scope CSS settings.

I have done the obvious things which is to contain the widget within an IFrames, which works, but creates its own set of problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions to your problem:

1. Use narrower scopes for global CSS settings. You might have class names that clash, or are shared between other elements on your page and the widget.
2. Wrap the widget around a container with a specific class/ID, and then override/reset the styles for elements in that container.

Comment: Thanks could not do anything about 1) since one was Primefaces and the other one was the client's own mandatory CSS. But 2) works great.